# JQuery multiple divs moveable, closeable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with my JQuery:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $(".box").draggable({cancel: ".box-content"});
            $(".close").click(function(){
                $(this).parent().parent().hide();
            });
            $("li[rel='nav']").click(function(){
                purl = $(this).attr('href');
                $.ajax({url:purl, success: function(data){
                    $("main").append(data);
                }});
            });
            $( "div" ).disableSelection();
        });
    </script>
```

It's supposed to open div boxes, move them and close them when I click on the close <"a"> (without the ""). It should be possible to to open boxes next to each other and (like "rooms, inventory, shop" but not "rooms, rooms, rooms").

That's the Navigation:

```
<ul class="navigation-bar">
            <li href="include/rooms.php" class="rooms" rel="nav"></li>
            <li href="include/inventory.php" class="inventory" rel="nav"></li>
            <li href="include/shop.php" class="shop" rel="nav"></li>
            <li href="include/friends.php" class="friends" rel="nav"></li>
            <li href="include/customize.php" class="customize" rel="nav"></li>
            <li href="include/purse.php" class="purse" rel="nav"></li>
            <li href="include/news.php" class="news" rel="nav"></li>
            <li href="include/help.php" class="help" rel="nav"></li>
            <li href="logout.php" class="logout"></li>
        </ul>
```

The boxes are opened in the <"main"> (without the "") like this:

```
        <div id="rooms" class="box box-mid">
            <div class="box-headline blue">
                Navigation
                <a href="#" id="close" class="close"></a>
            </div>  
            <div class="box-content">
                Choose a room to enter or make your own room!       
            </div>  
        </div>
```

Comment: What is exactly your problem? Have you some errors in the console? Could you create a JSFiddle with this to help us helping you? You should try to `console.log('test')` in your function to be sure it's well executed. An other thing, you should put all your **JS** stuff at the end of the `<body>`, not in the `<head>`.

Comment: create a demo if possible!!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xzvz68Lk/ I don't know if this will help you, because the divs are in /includes/ folder. The problem is that it only opens the boxes, but they are not moveable or closeable and they open not like "rooms, inventory, shop" but like "rooms, inventory, rooms, rooms, inventory". You can see it here: http://hubbhotel.ga/hotel/index.php

Comment: you want those alerts to be draggable and closeable?

Comment: Yes, but they should also be opened next to each other but not more than 1 time (after you close them they can be opened again).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(function() {
    $(".box").draggable({cancel: ".box-content"});
    $(".close").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().hide();
    });
    $("li[rel='nav']").click(function(){
        purl = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({url:purl, success: function(data){
            $("main").append(data);
            $(".box").draggable("destroy");
            $(".box").draggable({cancel: ".box-content"});
            $(".close").unbind('click').click(function(){
                $(this).parent().parent().hide();
            });
        }});
    });
    $( "div" ).disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on draggable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'

Comment: I changed it, now I can open as many as I want, drag and close them :)

Comment: if you find the answer useful then you should accept/upvote the answer.